# Viewpager and fragment on android studio

Tags: android

android developers please help, I Have viewpager with fragments, when i slide in the pages and reached the last page and then when i return to the first page again the fragment of the first page loads its default display.Please help..here is my code in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView navList;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private Menu menu;
    private float lastTranslate = 0.0f;
    private FrameLayout mainframe, galleryframe;
    private Frag_Gallery fragGallery;
    private Frag_Create fragCreate;
    private Frag_Account fragAccount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mainframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentholder);
        galleryframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.galleryholder);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0b115e"));
        Main_Menu Menu_data[] = new Main_Menu[]
                {
                        new Main_Menu(R.mipmap.gallery_icon, "Gallery"),
                        new Main_Menu(R.mipmap.create_icon, "Create Your Own"),
                        new Main_Menu(R.mipmap.account_icon, "My Account"),
                        new Main_Menu(R.mipmap.contact_icon, "Contact Us")
                };
        MainMenuAdapter adapter = new MainMenuAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listviewmain_item_row, Menu_data);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);

        View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewmain_header_row, null);

        navList.addHeaderView(header);

        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
        navList.setDivider(null);
        navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                loadSelection(position);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            }
        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.opendrawer, R.string.closedrawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        actionBar.setTitle("");

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        loadSelection(0);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.gallery_icon);
                        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.create_icon_off);
                        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.account_icon_off);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.gallery_icon_off);
                        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.create_icon);
                        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.account_icon_off);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.gallery_icon_off);
                        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.create_icon_off);
                        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.account_icon);
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.gallery_icon);
        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.create_icon_off);
        menu.getItem(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.account_icon_off);
        return true;
    }

    private void loadSelection(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                actionBar.setTitle("Gallery");
                pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                break;
            case 2:
                actionBar.setTitle("Design");
                pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                break;
            case 3:
                actionBar.setTitle("Account");
                pager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                break;
            case 4:
                actionBar.setTitle("Contact us");
                break;
            default:
                actionBar.setTitle("");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private Fragment fragment;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

            fragment = new Fragment();
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Frag_Gallery();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Frag_Create();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Frag_Account();
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note : that is intended behavior of viewpager. Setting setOffscreenPageLimit will cause higher memory footprint. If you wish to save changes made to fragment, you need to implement some kind of storage solution.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(X);
```

where X is the count of the pages you want to save so the ViewPager wont rebuild them.